# terminal - run java app in background and how to close it?

Tags: java, linux, terminal, server

I have game server and I want to launch it on Asustor NAS Server. I have PuTTy and I write

```
nohup java -jar server.jar &
```

Good, it launch in background, but now I want to close it. How to do it? And how to know if app is running or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally when starting you get the pid returend like so:

```
~ $ nohup java -jar server.jar &
[1] 3305
~ $ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
```

to see if it is running you can issue

```
~ $ ps -ef | grep  server
user1  3305  2936  0 13:58 pts/1    00:00:00 java -jar server.jar
```

if you see a line like the above it is running. You may also hava a look at the nohup.out file, which is written to the directory you started the server in, by using

```
tail nohup.out
```

to kill the process issue kill . Where pid is the process id, you either remembered, or will find out by looking at the second row of the "ps -ef | grep  server" command, in our case 3305

```
kill 3305
```

kill without options tries to end the process gracefully. Read more abut kill and ps by using

```
man kill
```

and

```
man ps
```

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.
Get number of your job using:

```
jobs
```

then use `fg` command:

```
fg %job_num
```

When it will be on foreground you can press CTRL+C to kill the process.